# libavcodec/ffmpeg reports two channels when decoding, but segfaults when trying to access the second

Tags: c, ffmpeg, segmentation-fault, libavcodec

I am attempting to decode an audio file into raw pcm data using FFMpeg's libavcodec. I have the following code so far, but it segfaults when trying to access the second audio channel for some reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ao/ao.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 4096


#define AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE 20480
#define AUDIO_REFILL_THRESH 4096

int decode(AVCodecContext *dec_ctx, AVPacket *pkt, AVFrame *frame, uint8_t* out_data, int* index) {

    int i, ch;
    int ret, data_size;

    ret = avcodec_send_packet(dec_ctx, pkt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error submitting packet to decoder\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (ret >= 0) {
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(dec_ctx, frame);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error during decoding\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        data_size = av_get_bytes_per_sample(dec_ctx->sample_fmt);
        if (data_size < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to calculate data size\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < frame->nb_samples; ++i)
            for (ch = 0; ch < dec_ctx->channels; ++ch) {

                //Things go wrong here...
                memcpy(out_data + *index, frame->data[ch] + (data_size*i), data_size);
                *index += data_size;
            }
    }

    return 0;
}

int decode_audio_file(const char* path, uint8_t* out_data, int size) {
    const AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c = NULL;
    AVCodecParserContext *parser = NULL;
    int len, ret;
    FILE *f;
    uint8_t inbuf[AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE + AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE];
    uint8_t *data;
    size_t data_size;
    AVPacket *pkt;
    AVFrame *decoded_frame = NULL;


    avcodec_register_all();
    pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_FLAC);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    parser = av_parser_init(codec->id);
    if (!parser) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Parser not found!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!c) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate audio context!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    f = fopen(path, "rb");
    if(!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", path);
        exit(1);
    }

    data = inbuf;
    data_size = fread(inbuf, 1, AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE, f);

    int index = 0;  
    while (data_size > 0) {
        if (!decoded_frame) {
            if (!(decoded_frame = av_frame_alloc())) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate audio frame\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        ret = av_parser_parse2(parser, c, &pkt->data, &pkt->size, data, data_size, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, 0);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while parsing\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        data += ret;
        data_size -= ret;

        if (pkt->size)
            decode(c, pkt, decoded_frame, out_data, &index);
        if (data_size < AUDIO_REFILL_THRESH) {
            memmove(inbuf, data, data_size);
            data = inbuf;
            len = fread(data + data_size, 1, AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE - data_size, f);
            if (len > 0)
                data_size += len;
        }
    }
    avcodec_free_context(&c);
    av_parser_close(parser);
    av_frame_free(&decoded_frame);
    av_packet_free(&pkt);

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int bsize = 1024*1024*60;
    uint8_t* audio_buffer = calloc(bsize, sizeof(uint8_t));
    decode_audio_file("testsong.flac", audio_buffer, bsize);
}
```

Here is the offending line:

```
memcpy(out_data + *index, frame->data[ch] + (data_size*i), data_size);
```

If you access `frame->data[0]` it's fine, but if you attempt to access `frame->data[1]` it segfaults. The context reports two channels and the file contains two channels (tried with several different tracks).
But it gets even weirder. If I switch the offending line to `memcpy(out_data + *index, frame->data[0] + (data_size*i*2 + ch), data_size);`
 it will have the left channel with correct data and the right channel is white noise. <strike>This tells me (and I could be wrong) that the first channel actually contains 2 channels of audio interleaved, the actual left channel, plus a junk channel of white noise.</strike>
I was wrong, I forgot to multiple `ch` by `data_size`. If the line is `memcpy(out_data + *index, frame->data[0] + (data_size*i*2 + ch*data_size), data_size);` things seem to work as expected. This all still seems very sketchy though so if anyone can thoroughly explain what's happening here, that would be nice.

I have been working off the decode_audio example available in the ffmpeg documentation [here](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decode_audio_8c-example.html) although modified slightly.

This ALSO happens if I use the vanilla example with the only change being setting the codec to FLAC, so I assume it's a bug in the library. In that case, how can I work around it.

Comment: what is the exact format of the decoded audio frame ?

Comment: 44.1/16 stereo PCM, the ffmpeg docs gave me the impression the frame split the channels in the data array, at least that's what the examples show.

Comment: you should give the exact format like `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16` this is linear format which means only `data[0]` (or just `data`) is correct and channels are interleaved. You probably thinking your format is `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P` this is planar format, which may be not the case.

Comment: Adding this in case it helps someone with a similar issue:
You can get the exact format name by doing:
`int sample_fmt = c->sample_fmt;`
`char * sample_fmt_name = av_get_sample_fmt_name(AVSampleFormat(sample_fmt));`
The sample format enum, or the corresponding sample format name, will be something like `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16` or `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P` (if the samples are stored as signed 16 bits). If it ends with P it means planar, if not it means the channels are packed. It sounds like you are operating off the assumption they are planar. Would be interesting to know which one they are.